# How to load an image using absolute path in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have images on my file server, and the locations of the images stored in the database. Let's say all my images are stored in folder

`C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\images\`

and I have following rows in my database

`C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\images\image1.png`
`C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\images\image2.png`

I want to display the images on a JSP page, using Spring MVC via annotations

I have configured the resource handler for the image folder

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/images/");
}
```

and i'm passing the file path loaded from database to the jsp file

here's how i want to display it

```
<c:forEach var="imgPath" items="${imagesList}">
    <img src="/images/${imgPath}" alt="">
</c:forEach>
```

I tried saving just file name in the database, or remove the `/images/` resource handler, and non of the methods works. How should I store my file names, and how do i access the files from some absolute path on my computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please fix the following things and try:

1. Fix the path:

For Windows file system, use 3 slashes.

`file:///C:/Users/mainserver/Desktop/images/`

2. Fix the database entries:

Just store the names of the images (e.g. image1.png, image2.png, etc), not the entire path.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the resulting value of the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag. Looks like at this moment it would be like this: `/images/C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\images\image1.png` that is obviously wrong. It should be `/images/image1.png`

> I tried saving just file name in the database

If it didn't work then there was another problem that need to be solved. But the approach was right, in the database you should have only file names without anything else.

Comment: yep, you were absolutely right about the `img` `src` attribute. Actually, changing the name back to just the image name instead of the full path in database did the work, when i tried from my other computer. Maybe it's because i did something wrong last time, or maybe there's something wrong with my environment on the other one. anyway thanks for your help